# Integrar aplicação Java com o Nagios

Tags: java, nagios

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que faz o monitoramento de ativos (ar-condicionados, lâmpadas, etc.) em uma determinada sala e a planta dessa sala está ilustrada no Nagios com os ativos em seus devidos lugares.

Eu gostaria que depois que minha aplicação fizesse uma verificação de status destes ativos (verificar se estão ligados ou desligados) fossem exibidos no Nagios esses status.

Como passar esses parâmetros para o Nagios? Como fazer com que o Nagios receba as informações da minha aplicação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu conheco, o Nagios nao trabalha desta forma. 
Pode ser que eue esteja enganado, mas na minha experiencia, ele atua como cliente dos sistemas a serem monitorados.
Em outras palavras, ele nao fica passivo, aguardando dados dos recuros monitorados. Ele tem um papel ativo e faz ele mesmo um levantamento do status dos recursos com uma frequencia pré-definida por script, podendo utilizar diferentes plugins e protocolos (a minha experiencia foi com HTTP).

Neste caso, sua aplicacao Java seria somente um mediador entre o Nagios e os recursos monitorados. Ela teria o seguinte papel:

receber requests do Nagios por JMX, HTTP ou algum outro protocolo suportado.

levantar o status dos recursos monitorados por socket.

repassar as informacoes para o Nagios (Se utilizar HTTP, como HTTP-Response do Request vindo do Nagios).

Comment: É isso mesmo. Minha aplicação ficará esperando uma requisição do Nagios e logo após fará um checkup nos ativos e retornará os status ao Nagios. Como proceder para realizar tal tarefa? Tem algum tutorial que possa mostrar como configurar o Nagios para enviar as requisições para aplicação e como a aplicação deve mandar as informações?

Comment: Caro Anderson, creio que estas perguntas relacionadas ao Nagios saem do escopo deste forum. Mas google é seu melhor amigo neste caso. Encontrei algumas coisas interessantes já: https://twindb.com/about-nagios-best-practices/, http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-publicservices.html, http://nagios-plugins.org/documentation/, http://wiki.monitoring-portal.org/nagios/tips/start. Há muito mais a ser encontrado. Boa sorte!

Comment: Não foge do escopo porque minha dúvida é de como integrar minha aplicação Java com o Nagios, não é somente em relação às configurações do próprio Nagios.

Comment: De qualquer modo agradeço pelas respostas.

Answer (score 4):

Já fiz algo parecido.

No meu caso, minha aplicacao Java recebia http requests do sistema Nagios e retornava as respostas em padores pre-definidos, de maneira que o Nagios podia mostrá-las.

Quando um request era recebido pela aplicacao, ela levantava o status dos recursos monitorados e mandava a resposta para o Nagios.
Se for utilizar este mecanismo, há 3 coisas a serem consideradas:

1. Qual o tipo de monitoramento a ser feito? Com alarme em caso de
   problemas nos recursos monitorados? Somente leitura do status nos
   recursos?
2. Tempo de resposta dos recusros monitorados tem que ser relativamente pequeno, para nao haver um http timeout, já que Nagios trabalha de forma síncrona.
3. Tipo de resposta sendo retornada ao Nagios:

   - deve conter todos os dados já prontos para que Nagios nao necessite calcular nada.
   - deve tambem conter mensagens legíveis e compreensíveis para os usuarios finais.

Espero ter sido claro suficientemente e poder ter ajudado.

Caso tenha perguntas, nao exite em escreve-las.

Comment: Minha aplicação se comunica com os controladores via socket. Estes controladores me enviam informações como temperatura atual do ambiente, se as lâmpadas e ar-condicionado estão ligados ou desligados... enfim, quando receber essas informações dos controladores queria enviar essas informações para o Nagios para que ele mostrasse na planta da sala, por exemplo, se uma lâmpada estiver apagada exibe uma imagem de uma lâmpada vermelha, se estiver ligada exibe uma imagem amarela.